# Error Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_ to

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Estoy intentando realizar una descarga de unas url que se encuentran en un archivo. Por lo que uso el siguiente bloque de codigo

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
  wget "$line"
done < file.csv
```

Pero al ejecutarlo tengo la siguiente salida:

```
https://base_url/uploads/products/medium/29-1-1556758770.png
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_NUMERIC to en_CO.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_TIME to en_CO.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_COLLATE to en_CO.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_MONETARY to en_CO.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_MESSAGES to en_CO.
--2020-03-03 10:07:38-- https://base_url/uploads/products/medium/29-1-1556758770.png
```

Esto falla porque al intentar ejecutar el wget la url contiene al final **%0D** Como puedo solucionar esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tiene nada que ver con el ciclo while, sino con el `locale` del sistema (lo aclararé más tarde). También la respuesta de @Alexmaister no parece arreglar la raíz del problema.

Como me gustó el problema, investigué un poco sobre el asunto del `locale`, mismo del que yo desconocía salvo el nombre y una ligera intuición de qué era.

Usando google translate para traducir lo que se dice en `locale(7)`, tenemos.

> ### `LOCALE(7)`
>
> ```
> locale [lo anterior lo puse literalmente] es un conjunto de reglas lingüísticas
> y culturales. Estos cubren aspectos como el lenguaje para mensajes, diferentes
> conjuntos de caracteres, convenciones lexicográficas, etc. Un programa necesita 
> poder determinar su ubicación y actuar en consecuencia para ser portátil a 
> diferentes culturas.
> ```

Tu locale parece ser `es_CO`, pero tu la tienes definida como `en_CO`.

Una opción que se me ocurre es cambiarla a otra usando `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` o `export LC_ALL=es_CO.UTF-8` (o a la que quieras) en el archivo de inicio de tu `shell`. Esto sobreescribe las variables de entorno `LC_` para establecer un *locale*.

Esto lo puedes hacer abriendo un editor de texto (yo usaré `vim` en mi ejemplo, tú sólo cambia el nombre) sobre el archivo de inicio de tu shell. Estos son `~/.bashrc` (si usas `bash`), `~/.zshrc` (si usas `zsh`) o `~/.config/fish/config.fish` (si usas `fish`, pero ahí no aplica esta respuesta).

```
vim "$(sed -r "s@-?(.*)@$HOME/\.\1rc@" <<< "$0" )" # Sólo para zsh o bash.
```

El comando anterior utiliza la salida del comando `sed` el cual recibe el nombre de la shell que se está corriendo. Puede ser `bash` o `-zsh` para los cuales funciona, y a eso le añade al inicio la dirección del `HOME` del usuario que lo corra y al final un `rc`.

Y hasta el final de tu archivo añade `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`; guarda, cierra y ya cambiaste la variable que hace referencia al *locale* a utilizar. Ahora sólo tienes que reiniciar tu shell o simplemente corre en la consola el comando de `export LC_ ... etc etc`

Puedes asegurarte de qué `locale` tienes con `locale -a` y ahí aparecería la variable que exportaste.

Lo anterior es si quieres cambiar la variable que indica el locale a usar. Si deseas generar uno (en caso de que no exista el de `es_CO.UTF-8`), puedes ver en el archivo `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` si está el locale que quieres (como `en_CO.UTF-8`, la cual no tendría que estar por el error de `en`, en lugar de `es`). Si está, entonces descomenta la línea correspondiente (la que tenga, por ejemplo `#es_CO.UTF-8`) en el archivo `/etc/locale.gen`; lo guardas y luego lo cierras.

Posteriormente podrás generar el *locale* corriendo:

```
$ locale-gen
```

en tu terminal.

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas ese ciclo while. 
El propio comando wget tiene una opcion (-i) para descargar archivos de diferentes URL`s

Quedando de la siguiente forma :

```
wget -i fichero.txt
```

Fichero.txt debe contener todas las URL`s requeridas.

Dices que el error es un %0D al final de la cadena, pero no veo que se muestre con el echo